# AngularJS v1.4.4 'expected identifier' error on IE10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, internet-explorer-10

I am creating an MVC5 with Angular JS project (angular version v1.4.4) in VS2013. I was coding along and everything was fine and then suddenly I started getting this error on launch:

> JavaScript critical error at line 5395, column 34 in http://localhost:63937/Scripts/angular.js\n\nSCRIPT1010: Expected identifier

I only get this error on IE10, it works fine on Chrome.

My references are in a layout file and look like this:

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
```

The HTML page contains the reference to the App.js file. I could post some code, but it doesn't even seem to be hitting the App.JS file. Anyone ran into this issue or have any suggestions as to where I should start looking for the issue? As far as I know, I reverted my code back to the point where it was working in IE10 but it still wont run.

Here is the specific function in the angular.js file that contains the line number from the error. The specific line is in return statement in the 'catch' function:

```
getPromise: function() {
  if (!this.defer) {
    this.defer = $q.defer();
  }
  return this.defer.promise;
},
then: function(f1,f2) {
  return this.getPromise().then(f1,f2);
},
'catch': function(f1) {
  return this.getPromise().catch(f1);
},
'finally': function(f1) {
  return this.getPromise().finally(f1);
}
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend you use version `1.3.18` since it's the last stable release. As of today the AngularJS team haven't released a stable `1.4.x` release yet.

Comment: @yvesmancera, are you sure? In Visual Studio 2013 NuGet Manager it's listed as a stable version

Comment: My bad, It looks like you're right, 1.4.4 is a stable release.

Comment: I found this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4641) on AngularJS, it says it affects IE8 but it might also be affecting IE10. It doesn't allow `catch` as an identifier since it's a reserved word on ES3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this was recently introduced specifically in `v1.4.4` according to the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#144-pylon-requirement-2015-08-13):

> **$animateCss**: make sure that skipBlocking avoids the pre-emptive transition-delay styling

To expand a bit more the line that's throwing the error for some context:

```
var $CoreAnimateCssProvider = function() {
  this.$get = ['$$rAF', '$q', function($$rAF, $q) {

    var RAFPromise = function() {};
    RAFPromise.prototype = {
      done: function(cancel) {
        this.defer && this.defer[cancel === true ? 'reject' : 'resolve']();
      },
      end: function() {
        this.done();
      },
      cancel: function() {
        this.done(true);
      },
      getPromise: function() {
        if (!this.defer) {
          this.defer = $q.defer();
        }
        return this.defer.promise;
      },
      then: function(f1,f2) {
        return this.getPromise().then(f1,f2);
      },
      'catch': function(f1) {
        return this.getPromise().catch(f1);
      },
      'finally': function(f1) {
        return this.getPromise().finally(f1);
      }
    };
//... more code
```

This `$CoreAnimateCssProvider` wasn't included in `1.4.3` so it's definitely new.

My suggestion is that you try version `1.4.3` for now, until this bug is fixed.

Comment: I tried 1.4.3 and angular.min.js just threw a new error: SCRIPT5007: Object expected File: angular.min.js, Line: 7, Column: 238. And this was in IE 11.0.9600. Also tried 1.6.1 with another error at a .catch.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in IE 11.0.9600. I tried 1.4.3 and angular.min.js just threw a new error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Object expected 
File: angular.min.js, Line: 7, Column: 238.
```

Also tried 1.6.1 which threw another error at a different ".catch" in the js.

However, this error could also be caused by the doctype being screwed up and IE trying to parse things in an old mode. To fix, either add to your web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=10" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Or, in your master layout page add:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

And also check your doctype declaration is the simple:

```
<!doctype html>
```

On a side note, there are several other gotchas with using angularjs in IE browsers (even the newest ones), which comes down to using:

1. ng-style tags instead of style="{{ someCss }}"
2. ng-attr-type tags instead of type="{{ someExpression }}" in buttons
3. ng-attr-value tags instead of value="{{ someExpression}}"
4. ng-attr-placeholder tags instead of placeholder="{{ someExpression }}"

See [IE compatibility with angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)